# UIButton cannot clicked after adding to another uiview

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uiscrollview, uibutton

I try to make the slideshow using uiscrollview, it will be triggered by slide event from uiscrollview.

Everything works fine except I try to add uibutton to the view, the button can be added and shown in the view but when I try to click the button, it does not triggered the function that I have stated in the addTarget function.

Anyone knows how to triggered the function assigned to the button?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your view hierarchy in Interface Builder ?

Comment: @Nathan14045 put a break point and test.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo sorry, I have not earned enough point to post the image

Comment: @TusharSharma I have tried but it did not hit the function stated in addtarget function

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo here is the url of the screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/8s2n4

Comment: Which one language you use

Comment: @SakirSherasiya I use swift 3.0

Comment: Are you sure no view overlaps your button ? Even a transparent one.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo yup, I am sure here is the view hierarchy http://imgur.com/a/zUhsa the skip button is on the bottom with the blue border

Comment: @Nathan14045 on which view do you want this button ?? The inner most view as shown in your image??

Comment: @TusharSharma yes, the hierarchy of the view already correct..

Comment: @Nathan1405 your button is outside of your view hierarchy. Drag that button inside your hierarchy where there are 2 more labels.

Comment: @TusharSharma still did not work..

Comment: @Nathan14045 show your storyboard connection image and controller class connection image.

Comment: @TusharSharma unfortunately, I did not use storyboard, for the view controller I implement it programmatically and for the view that will be slide I use xib and use Abstract factory pattern to produce multiple page with the same layout.

Comment: @Nathan14045 show your controller code.

Comment: @Nathan Show code for button .

Answer (score 0):

First Create func:

```
 func messagePrint(_ sender:UIButton)  {
        print("function called")
    }
```

Then **addTarget** into UIButton:

```
btnDemo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(messagePrint(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

In Above code **btnDemo** is UIButton Outlet.

Comment: what is your email?

Comment: **@objc func skipButtonClicked()** .   remove   **@objc**

Comment: removed it but still cannot triggered

Comment: put target as **self**